# How to choose one row from each seven dataframe to form a new dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have seven dataframes now, they have same structures including 41 rows and 12 columns. Now I want to choose one row from each dataframe to get a new dataframe. I can get 41^7 new dataframes theoretically so that I can run regressions with all of them. My target is to get a range of coefficient of my most important independent variable, but now my crucial step is get these 41^7 new dataframes. What should I do?

I have done a panel regression with 30 individual and 12 semi-year. For my most important variable, I calculated it due to its partly missing. Now I want to adjust its method of calculation to get a interval of coefficient. My process met an obstacle here.

```
FIT <- t(cbind(FITgan[1,],FITxin[1,],FITqing[1,],FITnei[1,],FIThe[1,],FITshan[1,],FITshann[1,]))
```

**This is my attempt for one combination, the number of whole combination is 41^7(7 dataframes, each with 41 rows). I would like to get a list with all these results.**

The number of whole combination is 41^7(7 dataframes, each with 41 rows). I would like to get a list with all these results. Thanks!!

Comment: So you want `194,754,273,881` dataframes and run regression on them?! I could be wrong but there's probably a better approach for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not clear to express myself. I get a variable in my regression in weighted approach. But I have no evidence if my weight is the best. So I wonder if I can adjust the weight to get a interval so that my former result is more credible. I adjust the weight 20% up and down by each 1%, so I get total 40 another data for each observation. If I change the range of weight variation or unit, I can reduce the number of new dataframe. But if you have a better approach, please teach me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this questions belong here. It rather sounds to be a topic for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). As you probably should not do a regression on 41^7 dataframes I would suggest a bootstrapping approach:

1. sample from your true observations WITH replacement 41 times.
2. run your regression
3. save coeffiecients of interest
4. repeat step 1-3 maybe 10,000 times
5. estimate a simulated distribution from your coefficients of interest

This will lead you to a better understanding of the underlying uncertainty of your parameters.